# while loop is acting weird

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm about to write a little VBScript to run some actions:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 6000 
while k < 5
    while h < 5
        while j < 20
            while i < 70
                WScript.Sleep 1000 '*1s
                WshShell.SendKeys "M"
                i = i+1
            wend
            WshShell.SendKeys "{right}"
            WScript.Sleep 30000 '*30s
            WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
            WshShell.SendKeys "--------------------------------------"
            WScript.Sleep 6000 '*6s
            j = j + 1
        wend
        WshShell.SendKeys "{right}"
        WScript.Sleep 900000 '*15min
        WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"  '* F5 let print the actual date in ms notepad
        WScript.Sleep 6000 '*6s
        h = h + 1
    wend
    WScript.Sleep 2500000 '*41min
    k = k + 1
wend
```

When I run the script and let the output pass into a text file the file looks like below. The really weird thing is not that the script didn't run these 70 M, actually I believe it can't run a while loop inside a while loop.

```
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM12:29 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:29 15.08.2015 //line 1
--------------------------------------12:30 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:30 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:30 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:31 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:31 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:31 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:32 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:32 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:32 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:32 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:33 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:33 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:33 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:34 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:34 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:34 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:35 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:35 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:35 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:35 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:36 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:36 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:36 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:37 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:37 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:37 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:38 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:38 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:38 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:38 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:39 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:39 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:39 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:40 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:40 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:41 15.08.2015
--------------------------------------12:55 15.08.2015 //line 37
12:56 15.08.2015
13:10 15.08.2015
13:11 15.08.2015
13:25 15.08.2015
13:26 15.08.2015
13:40 15.08.2015
13:41 15.08.2015
13:55 15.08.2015
13:56 15.08.2015
```

Even the time differences btw. each print action is realy weird, or that these "-----" are printed 37 times and then only the date were did it get these 37 loops, im totally confused.

Does anyone know a similar problem or know how I can handle this, that the script is exactly doing what I want?

Comment: You never reset your counters, so the inner loops never repeat after completing once. Also, you don't initialize your counters, so their initial values may not be 0. With that said: DO *NOT* USE `SendKeys`. EVER. If you want text written to a text file use the appropriate `FileSystemObject` methods for that.

Comment: ohhh nooo of course thanks men!

Comment: stupid fault of mine^^